# Multiple entry amalgamation in a ListBox

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, listbox

I have a DataTable with two columns in it. One column is a surname, the second is a first initial. I kind of get the idea about using DisplayMember and ValueMember to display a list made up of one column, bit is there a way to display both columns? I would use a DataTable forms object to do this, but I also want to avoid seeing the title of each column. the resulting ListBox entry would ideally look like this:

```
Bloggs, J
Bloggs, J
Bloggs, J
```

This also enables each entry to be selectable, thus editable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(If I understand your qquestion correctly)

You can add a third `Column` to your `DataTable` and set its `Expression` property to

```
LastName + ', ' + FirstName
```

Then use it as `DisplayMember` property.

The column is only in your data table and not related to database and will compute in your application.

> [DataColumn.Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx)
>   One use of the Expression property is to create
>   calculated columns. For example, to calculate a tax value, the unit
>   price is multiplied by a tax rate of a specific region. Because tax
>   rates vary from region to region, it would be impossible to put a
>   single tax rate in a column; instead, the value is calculated using
>   the Expression property.
>
> A second use is to create an aggregate column. Similar to a calculated
>   value, an aggregate performs an operation based on the complete set of
>   rows in the DataTable. A simple example is to count the number of rows
>   returned in the set. This is the method you would use to count the
>   number of transactions completed by a particular salesperson